# Confusion on Recursion and why my List isn't staying Updated?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] arr = new int[]{2,3,4,5};
        int[] min = new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE};
        int tgt = 7;
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> sol = new ArrayList<>();
        
        recursion(arr, tgt, lst, min, sol);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < sol.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(sol.get(i));
        }
      
    }
    
    public void recursion(int[] nums, int tgt, List<Integer> lst, int[] minLen, List<Integer> sol) {
        if (tgt < 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (tgt == 0) {
            if (lst.size() <= minLen[0]) {
                minLen[0] = lst.size();
            }
            sol = lst;
            return;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            List<Integer> cpy = new ArrayList<>(lst);
            cpy.add(nums[i]);
            recursion(nums, tgt - nums[i], cpy, minLen, sol);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic logic of what I'm trying to do is, given an array of numbers and a target, I want to return the smallest list of numbers that can be summed up to the target (in this case I'd want to return either {3,4} or {5,2}. I call a recursive function that breaks down my problem until I reach a base case in which I return or do some work on my `sol` list. `lst` is there to build up my current list in that recursive path while `sol` is there to update whenever I find a new path that is the new minimum length. However, what I think is happening is that when `sol` updates and returns, it becomes reset so `sol` is empty when it returns to main. I thought the `sol` list was being added to the Heap and would persist across all the calls when updated (like the `minLen` array)? Or am I missing something. What would be a way to get around this while maintaining my logic (I don't want to return a value but would rather have some data structure that just updates and that I could just return from my main function).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a code as follows:

```java
    public void recursion(int[] nums, int tgt, List<Integer> lst, int[] minLen, List<Integer> sol) {
        //... removed not relevant code
        sol = lst;

    }
```

What you are really doing is just assigning `sol` variable to point to a different object. That doesn't have any affect on the `sol` variable that you passed as an argument in the main method. That's because java passes arguments by value. In this case value is a reference to the object.

In the `recursion` method that reference is copied into `sol` variable (parameter). So, when you assign it a different value (`sol = lst`), you only update value of this one variable, that is local to the function.

You have two solutions here:

1. Just add all values into a list that `sol` (passed as argument) points to.
2. (better) just return result from within a function and assign it to new variable in main method.

It' usually a bad idea to modify objects passed into the function (unless that's the job of the function - like `sort` function). It's (almost) always better to return result with a `return` statement.